# Are user defined constructors and member functions inline by default?

Tags: c++, constructor, inline, member-functions

Let's have

```
class ClassA
{
public:
ClassA() = delete;
ClassA(int InObjectID):ObjectID(InObjectID){};
int GetID(){return ObjectID;};
private:
const int ObjectID;
}
```

a. Is the function ClassA(int) inline by default?

b. Is the function GetID(void) inline by default?

Comment: Note that while these two functions are implicitly inline, it's not because they're user-defined. It's because they're defined in the class definition.

Comment: Note that `inline` does not refer to the inlining of function calls, but to whether there can be definitions in more than one translation unit.

Comment: @molbdnilo great comment. I would've asked about that specific point.

Comment: @JohnFilleau great comment. I actually asked because I found a compile error for file-scoped, header-defined functions, and not for member functions in class definition in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a. Is the function ClassA(int) inline by default?
>
> b. Is the function GetID(void) inline by default?

Yes. Member functions that are defined within the class definition are implicitly inline.